# Only some URLs not loading in Webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, url, webview

Code

```
    final WebView mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.onlineradiofm.in/");
```

Im trying to load this URL in webview and the webview is empty.
What's wrong with this URL?
I tried replacing the URL with other links and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a SSL handshake failed for HTTPS URL.

for debugging the webview, pls add following line  and you can inspect webview Using chrome browser chrome://inspect.

```
     WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

Step-1: Create a webclient:

```
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, 
                                       SslError error) {
            //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.proceed(); // which ignores ssl errors and proceed further
        }
    };
```

Step-2: add client into webview

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Happy coding...

Comment: All Heroes don't wear capes.